# Django: Is it possible to get field values for a list of objects in bulk?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

This is probably a silly question, but for some reason I just cannot find a way to do this:

I am working on a recommendation engine in Django, which recommends movies based on the similarities between your taste and other users' tastes. Since every database access takes time, I try to use bulk methods as much as possible. However, at one point I need to get the movie that is associated with a certain vote, and I just cannot figure out how to do this in bulk:

The relevant models are:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
...
voters = models.ManyToManyField(Voter)
...
```

and

```
class MovieVote(models.Model):
    rating = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    voter = models.ForeignKey(Voter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
```

And the one line that currently takes 80%(!) of the time of the whole recommendation process is:

```
for otherVote in listOfOtherVotes:
    ...    
    movie = otherVote.movie
    ...
```

Is there any way to look up the foreign key "movie" for the whole list of votes at once? And ideally return it as a dictionary that maps each vote to the movie?

Comment: `for otherVote in listOfOtherVotes.select_related('movie'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `listOfOtherVotes` is a `QuerySet`, you can use [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the query, and thus fetch the details of the related `.movie`s in the *same* query, thus avoiding to fetch each `.movie` with an extra query:

```
for otherVote in listOfOtherVotes.select_related('movie'):
    # …
    movie = otherVote.movie
    # …
```